# How do I disable audio jack detection In Windows 10 without using Realtek HD Audio Manager?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, windows-registry, realtek-hd-audio

I have a headphone jack with a broken sensor. The headphones are normally supposed to turn on when they're plugged in. Because the jack is broken, however, my computer only detects that my headphones are plugged in when I push or tilt the plug, and that's the only time I can get sound out of them. Therefore I'd like to control this feature manually and force the sound to come out of my headphones all the time.

I've found registry keys that can be edited for Windows 7 and 8 which give this functionality, but none for Windows 10.

Realtek's HD Audio Manager has a "Disable Front Panel Jack Detection" option which gives this functionality, but Realtek's skin for Dell motherboards, which my computer has, does not include this option.

So I was thinking: Perhaps this Dell skin is only cosmetic. If I could find out which registry key is changed when someone else checks the "Disable Front Panel Jack Detection" box in their Realtek Audio Manager, I could edit that same key on my computer, and achieve the same functionality.

Does anyone know which key this is?

Comment: Did you try the drivers directly from Realtek? I've had similar issues where the MS-supplied drivers had a clipped interface. Replacing with the ones from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/) fixed all issues.

Comment: Yes I did. As best as I can figure based on my research, the UI you get depends on the motherboard you have. If that's not actually the case, I'd love to know.

Comment: I don't know, both machines here have the same mobo, ASUS. Both defaulted to a crappy MS control panel rather than the shiny colour one with individual speakers distances, EQ curves etc. Swapping to the proper one from Realtek fixed them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out! I don't know for sure if this will work for everyone, but it worked for me under Windows 10 while using Microsoft High Definition Audio Device Driver version 10.0.14393.0.

1. Press Windows Key + R.
2. Type `regedit`, press Enter.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0007\GlobalSettings`.
4. Right-click the REG_BINARY `EnableDynamicDevices`, click Modify, and set it to 0.
5. Reboot.

Windows will now display your headphones as an available audio device, whether you have headphones plugged into the jack or not.

To undo this change, repeat the previous steps, but set `EnableDynamicDevices` to 1

Comment: Mine was in 0001, but it worked. Thanks

Comment: This one works great even without the full-fledged manufacturer driver. Great !

Comment: The index value, after the class GUID will vary according to your system specifics; search through them looking for the one with the DriverDesc of "Realtek High Definition Audio".

Comment: Also, you need to have admin privileges

Comment: moved to 0008 after recent update

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my issue too! It came out of nowhere. I suggest to navigate to ```HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet``` and look for ```EnableDynamicDevices``` then setting it to 0 as you suggested.

Comment: This didn't work, but this did:  https://superuser.com/questions/1594949/windows-10-version-2004-19041-508-and-previous-how-to-disable-front-panel-ja/1594950#1594950

Comment: For those with Realtek driver you need to first install the High Definition Audio Device Driver through Windows Device Manager. Find your Realtek Device under Sound, video .... There Update Driver, Browse my computer for drivers. And finally Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer. Then the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a (5 years old) Dell (inspiron 15 3542) laptop with an audio jack 3.5 for headphones and windows 10a and "realtek high definition audio" driver.
My original problem was that I use my headphones a lot, so much that my previous laptop audio jack 3.5 output stopped working after a while.

My solution was of buying an 3.5 extension cable so I don’t have to unplug my cable from the laptop every time but only from the extension cable.

That's great, However, now windows doesn't auto detect my headphones every time it is plugged.

I tried finding a manually way for changing sound to be from my headphones instead of my laptop's speakers.
I had searched all over the internet for hours but nothing. This is because Realtek consider the computer's speakers and headphones as exactly the same device.

I found some solutions that DO work for me:

1. Just uninstall (and DO NOT reinstall) "realtek high definition audio" driver from the "Device Manager" list of windows 10. Then restart computer.
   Windows 10 will find out that there is a missing driver and will install a default driver of it's own that works great and separate  computer's speakers and headphones to 2 different devices.
2. If you have a Bluetooth (speakers or headphones), just connect one of them to computer and now you will have 2 different devices.
3. If you extend your screen with another HDMI monitor, you can look for audio jack 3.5 in your monitor and use it for your headphones for example.
4. Buy a splitter (of audio jack 3.5 cable) and external speakers. connect the speakers and headphones to the splitter and you are good to have audio in both of then at the same time. Do you want stopping one of them (speakers or headphones), just click an turn it off.

Sources:

1. Realtek drivers: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software
2. Troubleshoot Headphones not Working / Detected on Windows 10: https://appuals.com/fix-computer-doesnt-recognize-headphones/
3. How do I disable audio jack detection In Windows 10 without using Realtek HD Audio Manager? - Super User [How do I disable audio jack detection In Windows 10 without using Realtek HD Audio Manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/1194448/how-do-i-disable-audio-jack-detection-in-windows-10-without-using-realtek-hd-aud)
4. Windows 10 Version 2004 (19041.508) and Previous - How to Disable Front Panel Jack Detection - Realtek Audio - Super User  [Windows 10 Version 2004 (19041.508) and Previous - How to Disable Front Panel Jack Detection - Realtek Audio](https://superuser.com/questions/1594949/windows-10-version-2004-19041-508-and-previous-how-to-disable-front-panel-ja/1594950#1594950)
5. Fix: Realtek HD Audio Manager Headphones and Speakers Show Up as Same Device - Appuals.com https://appuals.com/fix-realtek-hd-audio-manager-headphones-and-speakers-show-up-as-same-device/