# How to edit registry keys for RealTek Audio Microphone and Speakers?

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-registry, speakers

[How do I disable audio jack detection In Windows 10 without using Realtek HD Audio Manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/1194448/how-do-i-disable-audio-jack-detection-in-windows-10-without-using-realtek-hd-aud/1194903#1194903?newreg=1e1c7c26d6054f619f80412bc9f46ceb)

I'm trying to follow the instructions for editing the registry keys from this previous thread but So I'm trying to do what the thread suggests but I can't find "EnableDynamicDevices"

Under "global settings" I get the options:

Default
centerLfeSwap
EQ
HpMode
HpShutsOffRearSpeaker
MicEQ
SpdifOutputEcho"

but no Enable Dynamic Devices

Can someone plz help?