# Windows 10 Version 2004 (19041.508) and Previous - How to Disable Front Panel Jack Detection - Realtek Audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, front-panel

How do you disable front panel jack detection in Windows 10 if the [Realtek Audio Control](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/realtek-audio-control/9p2b8mcsvpln?ocid=AID2000142_aff_7791_1338371&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) application won't install from the Microsoft Store?  I want my speakers and my headset to simultaneously output the same audio stream no matter which is plugged in.

I don't want my headphones being plugged into the front panel audio port to mute my speakers.  I want both my headset and my speakers to work at the same time outputting the same audio.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Realtek's new audio control panel required UAD drivers, which in turn realtek commits on every specific OEM to compile and release. Of course older hardware (and sometimes not even that) is left behind. Thankfully there is a [modded package](https://github.com/pal1000/Realtek-UAD-generic) providing a generic driver. Once you install that, the control panel will download by itself automatically.

Answer (score 8):

After numerous searches online, I initially could not find a way to have both my speakers (plugged into the back audio port of my motherboard) and my headset (plugged into the front panel audio port of my case) output the same sound stream simultaneously.  Plugging in my headset would mute my speakers.  However, I wanted my speakers and my headphones to work at the same time.

This [StackExchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/1194448/how-do-i-disable-audio-jack-detection-in-windows-10-without-using-realtek-hd-aud) talked about changing the `EnableDynamicDevices` registry key to disable front panel jack detection, but that didn't work for me, and it's completely wrong.

Since I have a dual-boot setup for Windows 7 and Windows 10, I booted into Windows 7 and used [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to capture the actual registry key change that occurs when you disable front panel jack detection using the `Realtek HD Audio Manager` application that is included with the drivers in Windows 7.

Unfortunately, in Windows 10, Microsoft decided that drivers should be slimmed down, so Realtek's drivers were changed to not include the `Realtek HD Audio Manager` software.  Instead, you're supposed to download and install the [Realtek Audio Control](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/realtek-audio-control/9p2b8mcsvpln?ocid=AID2000142_aff_7791_1338371&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) application from the Microsoft Store to get the functionality that was once included by default in the driver package (known as `Realtek HD Audio Manager` in previous versions of Windows).  But, no matter what I tried, I could not get `Realtek Audio Control` to install in Windows 10 Version 2004.

So, how did I get this to work?

1. Install (the installer will uninstall any currently installed Realtek audio driver versions, which is what you want) Realtek HD Audio Driver version R2.82 from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software.  The benefit to using these drivers is that additional settings will show up in the enhancements for your playback device (such as the Equalizer and Loudness Equalization options) as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

2. The next step is to find out the key number for your Realtek Audio device specific settings.  To do this, launch Registry Editor (Click on start and type "regedit"), and then go to the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`
3. Expand all of the `000*` folders, look for a `Settings` folder that contains a  `Drv8186_DevType` entry like so:

[image]

4. For each one of these folders, you'll need to create a new REG_BINARY entry in the `Settings` folder called `JackCtrl` like so:

[image]

The contents of the `JackCtrl` key should be set to `ff 82 40 00`

5. Make sure to do this for each `000*` folder that has a `Drv8186_DevType` sub folder within its `Settings` folder.
6. Restart your computer.  Audio should now play through your speakers and headset at the same time!

Here is a registry key export file you can import (but it may not work for you unless you adjust the `000*` entries to match where your `Drv8186_DevType` sub folder entries are in the `Settings` folder for each `000*` entry):

http://dinofly.com/files/windows/reg_disable_front_panel_jack_detection_windows_10_realtek_modified.zip

This is a disaster, and I hope Microsoft and Realtek will get their stuff together.  The fact I had to do all of this work to change one simple setting is ridiculous.  `Realtek HD Audio Manager` should be packaged with the driver like it used to be in Windows 7.  Then, things are as easy as this:

[image]

I was able to get some helpful information from this [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ftw6lq/realtek_audio_console_is_missing_from_the/) as well.  I hope this helps someone.  What a miserable experience this was!

**EDIT:**

I wrote this little .NET Framework 4.0+ utility that can detect the right `Settings` registry sub key and modify the correct `JackCtrl` registry hex value to disable front-panel audio detection:

https://dinofly.com/files/audio_tweaker_utility.zip

Please note, `Disable Front Panel Jack Detection` has been removed completely from newer Realtek drivers.  It appears newer drivers do not respect the old setting hex value.  Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Excellent research and answer!

Comment: OwN is a national treasure!

Answer (score 1):

This is more a compromise rather than a solution but if you have trouble installing Realtek Audio Control from MS Store (as I did), Realtek HD Audio Driver version R2.8**1** (R2.82 is the latest but as pointed out in the solution above, the Audio Manager is not bundled) is bundled with Realtek HD Audio Manager where you can quickly toggle the front panel detection off via the GUI.

If you can live with non-latest drivers, it'll save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

i know its a big ask but is there any way of updating this for the rear port please
I have a pioneer ddj flx-4 that uses WASAPI. If there is nothing connected to the audio port after you first plug in the FLX-4 it breaks WASAPI forever, and we have to reset the computer.

This is a pained experience.

Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).