# How can I make my 1/8" audio input "dumb" again?

Tags: windows-10, realtek-hd-audio

My Windows 10 notebook computer displays a Realtek Audio™ notification each and every time I plug in my headphones. The notification asks me what I plugged in (e.g. headphones, microphone, speakers, etc).

I realize this implies that the port can handle both input and output, but I don't need or want to use a microphone at this time. When plugging my headphones in, not only do they not work until I respond to the notification, but upon selecting "headphones" and pressing "okay", there is a painful crackle that comes through the headphones. I typically already have the headphones plugged in at the time of performing these actions.

I miss the good old days of just having a "dumb" 1/8" audio input and plugging my headphones in.

Is there a way I can turn this 1/8" audio jack into a good ol' "dumb" port again?

Comment: FWIW: 1/8" =3.175 mm. 3.5 mm is close, yes but not the same.

Comment: Does [How do I disable audio jack detection In Windows 10 without using Realtek HD Audio Manager?](https://superuser.com/q/1194448/272824) help?

Comment: @Hannu - Ha! I've never realized that. There are *many* resources on the web that use these dimensions interchangeably when referring to a 3.5mm audio jack / plug. Thanks for teaching me something!